# How to Insert images as file instead of inserting them in Database as BLOB

Tags: php, upload, image-file

I am new to php. i want to upload images from html form into file. i searched on net but unable to find anything helpful. Please tell me how to uplaod images in file rather than database. i know the method of uploading images in database, and its very easy. Is there any way like this of uploading images in file. sorry for my bad english.

```
$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$original_image=file_get_contents ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$name= $_FILES['image']['name'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

**This is an example from the link:**

```
<?php
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["image"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["image"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
?>
```

**Shorter example without support for multiple files/error checking:**

```
<?php
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
    $name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "uploads/$name");
?>
```

**Even shorter as a one-liner:**

```
<?php
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
?>
```

Comment: can you please tell me a simple way of doing it. Storing in database is very easy, and in 3 steps its done, but storing in file is way too long :(

Comment: @AftabAamir This IS an easy way and also the correct way of doing it. I've provided some simplified/shorter code snippets. The last two are functionally identical, they're just written in different ways. Shorter is not always better. The shortest one is the hardest to read.

Comment: 'Shorter example without support for multiple files/error' is easy

Answer (score 0):

do you mean you want to store your image to your server.

just use these two functions

```
<?php
    copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $imgPath); //copy your image to a specific path on server

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $imgPath); //copy your image to a specific path on server and delete uploaded image in temp folder
?>
```

Comment: @ntp Why are you using `copy` together with move_uploaded_file?

Comment: sorry about that. I mean we can use one of two functions to copy the temporary uploaded file to server path. I wanna show this: first  php uploads file to a temporary folder, then we can process this file in any way we want